# Does updating iOS apps delete library directory files?

Tags: ios, file

I keep save files in a private directory in my iPad app, namely the one returned when I use:

```
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Private Documents"];
```

Notice that I also append a subdirectory to it. When I update the app, users are telling me that their progress in the app is getting destroyed. Are files in this NSLibraryDirectory destroyed every time I update the app?  If so, should I be using NSDocumentDirectory instead?

Additionally, is there no way to make a further update to my app to remedy this without destroying all my my current users' save files? It doesn't seem like there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save them in the Documents folder, it is persistent across updates.

Monotouch:    `documentsDirectory = environment.specialfolder.personal;`

Objective-C:   `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)`

Comment: I don't really understand the line of code you have above. Can you explain? From what I gather, I can just use NSDocumentDirectory instead of what I did above and a subdir should be protected from being erased, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The code above gives you a string path to the documents Directory. Cleaner way of doing it IMO.

Comment: Chris, sure that you're talking about iOS? Because there is nothing like "environment.specialfolder.personal". Or you're talking about a custom solution to access this.

Comment: That syntax was for MonoTouch, I have updated it to reflect objective-c also.

Answer (score 17):

When a user downloads an app update, iTunes installs the update in a new app directory. It then moves the user’s data files from the old installation over to the new app directory before deleting the old installation. Files in the following directories are guaranteed to be preserved during the update process:

Application_Home/Documents

Application_Home/Library

Although files in other user directories may also be moved over, you should not rely on them being present after an update.

This is provided by apple officially. See this link : 
[iOS Developer Library - File Saved During App Updates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html)

Comment: the link "iOS Developer Library - File Saved During App Updates" is broken

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html

Comment: This link is still broken... I find it's very hard to find a definitive answer to this question. There are some docs on what file system locations are backed up to iTunes. However, is this the same behaviour across updates of the app direct from the app store on a device, i.e. without using iTunes at all?

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to add this info as a personal experience with a big online game. You can't rely at 100% that your "Document" and "Library" folder will always be there. In fact, you can't rely that your app folder will still be at the same place on your device after an update.

Let me explain it a little bit more. When you install an app on your device, the real path will be /var/mobile/Applications/[some class id]/[your app].app/...
We're not sure who defines the class id of your app (either the iOS or app store), but this Id can change when updating the game resulting in having your app in a totaly different folder so your old files aren't there anymore. Our QA experienced it and our users too.

I won't go through the details on how we found that out and how we managed to get around this (private company stuff, usual shit...), but you need to consider it if you're doing an app that affects tons of users and might be updated a couple of times. It might have been fixed since, but it's always good to have a backup plan.

Comment: Just one question, does your App's name add special chars in the name, or spaces? Because I wonder....

Comment: The path retrieved via apple APIs provides abstraction over what address your app is located at. During the update process, iOS backs up your documents directory to new location. The change in [some class id] or [you app].app name does/should not affect your Documents directory files. Your assumptions are incorrect IMO. ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW10

Comment: Same thing happened when I deployed my last app update in the Apple App Store. Suddenly all the local files stored in the library directory were deleted. I've made no modifications on that side and this was one of the many updates that I've made over the last 5 years (with no problems at all). My only suspect is that I've added push notifications support and so the app id have been updated. Could that be the problem?