# How can I delete from NSDocumentDirectory from the device (not from code)?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdocumentdirectory, nslibrarydirectory

There are plenty of answers on how to delete NSDocumentDirectory via code. Unfortunately, that's not what I'm looking for here.

I need a way to delete this from the device. Is there any way short of wiping the entire device and setting it up as a new device?

Deleting the app itself does not delete the NSDocumentDirectory for the application.

1) Will wiping the entire device and setting it up as a new device remove the NSDocumentDirectory?

2) Is there an easier and less costly way than #1 to remove this data off the device, via the device itself?

Comment: Why do you believe the NSDocumentDirectory is not deleted when you delete the app?

Comment: @Jessedc this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/5122894/1652166 mentions that NSDocumentDirectory data persists across updates. So I assumed it was the same when deleting the app. I have some data in NSDocumentDirectory. I delete the app, and when I reinstall the app (iCloud is off btw), the data in that directory is persisting.

Comment: Persisting across upgrades is different to delete/re-install.That data will not be persisting. If you delete the app the whole sandbox structure is removed. However, the app may be replacing the missing data upon launch after a fresh installation.

Answer (score 1):

The `NSDocumentsDirectory` for an iOS application [is stored within it's sandbox environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907381/what-is-the-documents-directory-nsdocumentdirectory) and will be removed when you delete the app from your device.

In iOS 9 you can see the individual storage of each app by going to **Settings -> General -> Storage & iCloud Usage -> Manage Storage** There is a shortcut here to delete the app.

Answer (score 1):

Using iTunes, you can delete files from NSDocumentDirectory of app X on your device if app X has activated UIFileSharingEnabled in the Info.plist.

1. Select your device on iTunes
2. Click the Apps tab and select your app X in the 'File Sharing'
   section.
3. You can delete files or directories.